# ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application") Not working when Outlook is open

Tags: javascript, activexobject

I have a javascript that works when Outlook is closed.  However, if outlook is open I receive "Automation Server" error.

```
var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application');
var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
email = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA');

email.Subject="Quote: "+ quoteNum + ' | Part#: '+ partNum;
email.To = "lcarreiro@epectec.com"; //who will to be going to
email.HTMLBody = "Quote Attached " + quoteNum;
email.display(0);
```

Any suggestions besides changing IE setting as I have already done so....

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late to help you but hopefully it helps anyone else who ends up here.

I was having the same issue and stumbled across https://stackoverflow.com/a/3779945/1002621 which answered a similar question.

Basically the issue is because when you run Visual Studio as an Administrator and Outlook with normal privileges you are no longer allowed to get an instance to the existing Outlook application but as it is single instance it won't create a new one.

This is only an issue if you initiate debugging directly from Visual Studio just starting your own instance of IE makes the problem go away.